# Аномальный трафик с Linux сервера

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu

Я купил VPS у хостинга. Его назначение - тестовый сервер для WebSockets на node js. Я туда поставил node js, CORS, express. Потом оказалось что для подключения с https к WebSockets надо только WebSockets Secure. В итоге я начал поиск дешевых SSL и остановился на Rapid SSL. Для меня получение SSL сертификата был темным лесом, и после нескольких раз генерации CSR и кучи убитого времени я решил немного остановится. После этого я 1 день почти ничего не делал и на следующее утро я просыпаюсь, захожу в админку хостинга, а мне вот такое письмо:

> Исходящий аномальный трафик с VPS
>   Уважаемый Ляховський Володимир Юрійович!
>   C Вашего сервера нами отмечается аномальный исходящий трафик. Мы были вынуждены ограничить доступ к Вашему серверу до получения от Вас деталей касательно причин данной ситуации. Для снятия ограничений обратитесь в технический отдел. **Дамп прикрепляем : dump.txt**

[dump.txt](https://adm.tools/uploads/pmessage_files/ext/0036/37.WDX5UKBQECM5AX8FSHPA9DUEW85LTVHF.txt)

Написал в техподдержку, так ничего и не выяснил.
Последнее сообщение от ТП:

> Добрый день
>   Дамп трафика Вам был отправлен в уведомлении 01.07.2019 23:47
>   Передайте его Вашему администратору или профильному специалисту который занимается администрированием сервера для изучения и устранения проблемы.

В итоге я совсем не понимаю о чем идет речь и как мое node js приложение могло куда-либо отправлять запросы, если это вообще было оно.

[Код тестового node js приложения](https://www.ladyboom.in.ua/test-node-server.js)

Comment: В логах только IP DNS от гугла и какой-то китайский IP. Блокировать исходящий трафик на левый IP не пробовали? Проверять на вирусы?

Comment: Проблема в том что судя по времени я в тот момент спал, а утром когда проснулся то мне заблокировали доступ к VPS и я не смог ничего посмотреть.

Comment: Из дампа видно, что нечто генерит 100 килопакетов (а это очень не мало) с хоста. Ну, теперь когда там сеть вырубили вряд ли получится найти виновного, но я б посмотрел вдруг осталась сетевая активность "вникуда" с помощью `tcpdump -nnvi any` и потом если она осталась, с помощью `netstat -tvaep` , `lsof -i`, `/proc/net/nf_conntrack` (если коннтрак там подрублен) выяснить от кого именно.

Comment: Есть npm пакеты со всякой ерундой типа "вирусы-трояны-воровщики криптовалют или криптодобытчики", может быть они?

Comment: Да, возможно дело и в пакете, буду разбиратся(

Comment: В новом npm после install пишет "audited 137 packages in 0.709s found 0 vulnerabilities", либо [npm audit](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/audit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мало информации для точного ответа, но можно дать пару советов:

---

Кто-то мог получить доступ к серверу, подобрав пароль от одного из юзеров. Например от к-л дефолтного юзера к-л программы (например postgresql, phpmyadmin etc). Их можно подобрать автоматическими скриптами, которые просто стучатся на сервер, пока не войдут. Часто в таком случае ставят в CRON задачи на что-нибудь, например скачивание малвари и прочее.

Что можно сделать?

1. Проверить содержимое `/var/log/syslog` - там логи авторизации на сервере разных юзеров. Если что-то подозрительное есть - можно отключить авторизации по паролю через `ssh` и настроить подключение по ключу. Его подбирать нужно будет годами, а не часами. Также полезно будет сменить дефолтный порт для `ssh`.
2. Проверить все `crontab` файлы всех юзеров - там могут быть следы взлома. Если файлы не из под `root` юзера сделаны, то можно просто их `root` юзеру передать, очистив предварительно. Так они не перезапишутся и работать не будут.
3. Проблема может быть и в `NodeJs` в виде к-л уязвимости. Тут поможет только удаление оной или апдейт на билд с фиксом. Маловероятно, однако я лично сталкивался со взломом личного сервера через уязвимость в `Jenkins`
4. Изучить все остальные логи сервера, если ничего не помогло - может быть найдётся что-то.

Хостеру надо написать, что есть идеи как починить и они должны будут включить доступ к серверу на к-л время (обычно несколько часов). Если за это время удастся найти и устранить проблему - пишите им, они проверят и всё вернётся на круги своя.